# Dismo showing mostly blank space

Tags: r, google-maps, dictionary, ggmap

I am plotting locations of my company's members' addresses in the United States.

I am using the package 'dismo' to create maps. Below is my code:

```
library(XML)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(dismo)

map <- gmap('New York',zoom=10)
plot(map)
```

Interestingly, the map is mostly blank. There's a tiny strip in the middle where I can see a little bit of the map plus the text 'Map data 2015 Google.'

ggmap works, but I need to use dismo, because my points need to be in Mercator style (not latitude and longitude coordinates). Anyone else have an idea for why this is happening? As far I can tell, this problem hasn't been mentioned on stack overflow or anywhere else on google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is causing the problem under the hood (is New York in Iowa?):

```
library(dismo)
geocode('New York')
#  originalPlace        interpretedPlace longitude latitude      xmin      xmax ...
#1      New York       New York, NY, USA -74.00594 40.71278 -74.25909 -73.70027 ...
#2      New York New York, IA 50238, USA -93.25993 40.85167 -93.26128 -93.25858 ...
```

And this is how you can work around it:

```
map <- gmap('New York, NY')
```

Comment: dang, I'm a dummy. Thanks for the help.